# XSLT set default value of '0' if node does not exsist

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to add three nodes together to define one total value, but am getting an output of "NaN" when one or more of the selected nodes does not exist in a given XML document. What is the easiest way to define a default value of '0' for the nodes 'double', 'triple', and 'hr' that will only be selected if that specific node does not exist in a given XML?

Here's an example of the input XML with all the nodes defined:

```
<totals> 
  <hitting ab="32" r="9" h="9" rbi="9" double="3" triple="1" hr="1" bb="5" hbp="1" sh="1" so="4" gdp="1" ground="13" fly="6" kl="2" hitdp="1"></hitting>  
  <fielding po="27" a="13" e="1" csb="0" sba="2"></fielding>  
  <hsitsummary adv="3" fly="6" ground="13" lob="6" rcherr="1" rchfc="1" rbi-2out="6" vsleft="0,0" advops="13,23" leadoff="4,8" pinchhit="0,0" w2outs="3,10" wloaded="1,1" wrbiops="5,16" wrunners="6,19"></hsitsummary>  
  <pitching ip="9.0" ab="31" bb="1" bf="32" double="1" er="0" fly="5" ground="9" h="4" kl="2" r="0" so="12" sho="1"></pitching>  
  <psitsummary fly="5" ground="9" leadoff="3,9" wrunners="1,10" vsleft="2,15" w2outs="1,10"></psitsummary> 
</totals>
```

And when only one ('double') is defined:

```
<totals> 
  <hitting ab="31" r="0" h="4" rbi="0" double="1" bb="1" sb="2" cs="1" so="12" ground="9" fly="5" kl="2"></hitting>  
  <fielding po="24" a="11" e="1" indp="1"></fielding>  
  <hsitsummary fly="5" ground="9" lob="5" rcherr="1" vsleft="0,0" advops="1,10" leadoff="3,9" pinchhit="0,2" w2outs="1,10" wloaded="0,0" wrbiops="0,7" wrunners="1,10"></hsitsummary>  
</totals>
```

And the XSLT transformation I've tried so far, which obviously only works when all three elements are defined. Otherwise it spits out a 'NaN'.

```
<xbh><xsl:value-of select="floor(totals/hitting/@double + totals/hitting/@triple + totals/hitting/@hr)" /></xbh>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `totals/hitting/@double + totals/hitting/@triple + totals/hitting/@hr` use `sum(totals/hitting/@double | totals/hitting/@triple | totals/hitting/@hr)`

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this by using `<xsl:choose>`:

```
<xbh>
  <xsl:variable name='xbh'
                select="floor(totals/hitting/@double + 
                              totals/hitting/@triple + 
                              totals/hitting/@hr)" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <!-- $xbh = $xbh will be false if $xbh is NaN -->
    <xsl:when test="$xbh = $xbh"><xsl:value-of select="$xbh" /></xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xbh>
```

Answer (score 0):

### XSLT 2.0

```
<xbh>
    <xsl:value-of select="totals/hitting/sum(@double | @triple | @hr)"/>
</xbh>
```